# Есть ли поисковые системы без ограничений?

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, интересует следующий вопрос. выполняю поиск по сайту следующим образом - поисковике пишу "`site:http://ask.fm москва`"(т.е. выведутся все страницы где писалось слово "москва") и гугл пишет что найдено 230 000 результатов, но мне даёт просмотреть только первые 40-60 страниц. есть ли возможность как-то получить оставшиеся хотя бы пару тысяч страниц? или же может есть другие поисковые системы которые выдают все найденные страницы?

Answer (score 2):

Оценка количества результатов на Гугле — очень грубая, и имеет хоть какое-то отношение к реальности только для тривиальных запросов "foo bar", а лучше вообще "foo".

У меня Гугл показывает только 7 страниц, что является верным признаком, что он больше ничего не может найти: [google.com/search? q=site:http://ask.fm+москва & num=100 & start=600 & filter=0](https://www.google.ru/search?q=site:http://ask.fm+%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0&num=100&start=600&filter=0).

Обычно, когда Гугл доходит до последней страницы, он изменяет счётчик на реальное значение:

- [https://www.google.com/search?q=йцуен&num=100&nfpr=1&start=0](https://www.google.ru/search?q=%D0%B9%D1%86%D1%83%D0%B5%D0%BD&num=100&nfpr=1&start=0) — 41 200 результатов
- [https://www.google.com/search?q=йцуен&num=100&nfpr=1&start=100](https://www.google.ru/search?q=%D0%B9%D1%86%D1%83%D0%B5%D0%BD&num=100&nfpr=1&start=100) — 128 результатов

При фильтре по сайту он почему-то так не делает.

Если хотите идеально точные результаты, пишите своего робота. Или договаривайтесь с сайтом, чтобы он предоставил вам необходимую информацию (разумеется, это возможно, только если вы хотите помочь сайту, а не наоборот; ну и масштабы ваши и сайта должны соотноситься).

Answer (score 1):

Поисковые системы не имеют ограничений на вывод страниц. Технически вывод количества страниц и самих страниц разделен, что дает разные результаты.

Лучше использовать `site:example.com` (без http). При этом поисковик покажет всё что есть у него **в индексе**. Иногда домены `www.example.com` и `example.com` — разные. Поэтому рекомендую смотреть оба. Это связано с отсутствием 'склейки' доменов, т.е. поисковик не признал что оба домена одинаковые по содержимому.

Не стоит ограничиваться только одним поисковиком, все же интенсивность сканирования и правила добавления в индекс у каждого разные.

Резюмирую: Поисковая машина показывает все страницы, имеющиеся в её 'памяти', если каких-то страниц нет — это не ограничение.

Comment: вот что постоянно пишет мне гугл "Извините, но Google не выдает более 1000 результатов, а вы запросили результаты с номера 1100.", а так же "Мы скрыли некоторые результаты, которые очень похожи на уже представленные выше (597)." и в любой поисковой системе(яндекс, рамблер, яхоо, нигма) показывает только 40-90 страниц..

Comment: В этом случае лучше использовать вариативные запросы. Гугл дает возможность посмотреть варианты.

Comment: вы не могли бы сказать как это сделать?

Comment: Вариативный запрос это когда один большой запрос, как `site:ask.fm москва` делится на меньшие, уточняется, например `site:ask.fm химки`. Таким образом результатов будет меньше. Парсим их, а потом снова другой уточняющий запрос.

Comment: так а что мне делать, если нужно получить пару тысяч страниц именно с москвой?

Comment: Использовать несколько поисковиков, сортируя и отсеивая повторяющиеся результаты. Кроме того, стоит рассмотреть возможность создания своего 'паука' для получения всех страниц, присутствующих на сайте.